# as Divs renderiza mas não aparece os dados passados, react

Tags: javascript, react

o programa pega dados de uma api e passa por um filtro que retorna para o componente products que deveria renderizar  na tela essa lista, o que ele faz mas os dados do produto não são parecem.

```
import Cards from '../function/card';
import renderlist from '../function/renderlist'; 
import {useEffect,useState } from 'react';


function Products(){      
       useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, []);
    const [list,setlist]= useState()

    async function fetchData() {
        const res = await renderlist()
        const list = res.map((valor) =><Cards value={valor} key={valor.name}/>)
        console.log(list)
        setlist(list)
        
    }
    return(<div>{list}</div>)

}
export default Products;
```

os componentes são renderizados na tela mas não aparece os dados passados, os components cards.

```
function Cards(unid){
    return(
    <div>
        <img alt={'aqui'} url={unid.url} ></img>
        <h1>aqui</h1>
    </div>
    )
}
```

eles aparece na tela com a quantidade certa mas não aparece as informações passadas nos parâmetros, apenas aparece divs vazias. verifiquei o list e parece como sendo um lista de objetos do tipo  {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element). o que aparece na tela do usuário apenas o "aqui" os demais dados não aparece, mas aparecem os span e img so que vazios...

Comment: onde você está chamando: `fetchData()`?

Comment: no useeffect, não sei porque não apareceu ali, mas já arrumei

Comment: se fez errado, dados você guarda em na variavel `list` e na `list` você utiliza o `map` e mostra o componente, do jeito que você fez só criou um `array` de componentes

Comment: poderia me explicar pouco melhor ? estou pouco perdido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa somente na variável `list` armazenar o resultado da `API` depois utilizar essa variável para mapear o componente `Cards`, exemplo:

```js
const data = [
  {
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png/091/fff'
  }, 
  {
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png/09f/fff'
  }
];
function Cards({unid}) {
    return (
      <div>
        <img alt={unid.url} src={unid.url} alt="" />        
        <h1>{unid.url}</h1>
      </div>
    )
}

function Products() {      
    const [list, setlist] = React.useState(data);
    React.useEffect(() => {
       fetchData();        
    }, []);    
    function fetchData() {
        // libera essas duas linhas
        //const list = await renderlist()
        //setList(list);
    }
    return (
      <div>{list.map((x, i) => (<Cards unid={x} /> ))}</div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Products/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Tinha também erros de `html` onde a `tag` `<img />` para monstrar a imagem é pela `src`.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Tem pessoa nessa rede que só sabe votar negativo e não contribui em nada!